# Restbed, Different methodes same paths are not allowed

Tags: restbed

I'm using a restbed c++ and I came across a issue when registering the same uri but with different methods (POST,GET,DELETE) on one resource.

When running the server and requesting a GET request it works fine, but for the POST request I get '405 Method Not Allowed'

PS,Note I had to trick the regex part even to be able to resister the methode.

- GET : language:[a-z_]
- POST: language:[ab-z_]

```
This if I register it with the same expression **set_path("/hello/{language:[a-z_]+}");**
#./so-rest 
Service accepting HTTP connections at 'http://[::]:1984'.
Resource published on route '/hello/{language:[a-z_]+}'.
So I kinda use these paths to be able to register them bought.
#./so-rest
Service accepting HTTP connections at 'http://[::]:1984'.
Resource published on route '/hello/{language:[a-z_]+}'.
Resource published on route '/hello/{language:[ab-z_]+}'.
```

Any Idea what is going wrong ?
Thanks.

This is a sample code.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <restbed>


using namespace std;
using namespace restbed;


class CustomLogger : public Logger
{
    public:
        void stop( void )
        {
            return;
        }

        void start( const shared_ptr< const Settings >& )
        {
            return;
        }

        void log( const Level, const char* format, ... )
        {
            va_list arguments;
            va_start( arguments, format );
            vfprintf( stderr, format, arguments );
            fprintf( stderr, "\n" );
            va_end( arguments );
        }

        void log_if( bool expression, const Level level, const char* format, ... )
        {
            if ( expression )
            {
                va_list arguments;
                va_start( arguments, format );
                log( level, format, arguments );
                va_end( arguments );
            }
        }
};


int main( const int argc , const char** argv)
{
    Service service;
    auto print_get =  []( const shared_ptr< Session > session ){
            std::string body = "Hello GET";
            session->close( OK, body, { { "Content-Length", ::to_string( body.length( ) ) } } );

        };
    auto print_post =  []( const shared_ptr< Session > session ){
            std::string body = "Hello POST";
            session->close( OK, body, { { "Content-Length", ::to_string( body.length( ) ) } } );

        };

    {
        auto resource = make_shared< Resource >( );
        resource->set_path("/hello/{language:[a-z_]+}");
        resource->set_method_handler( "GET" , print_get);
        service.publish(resource);
    }

    {
        auto resource = make_shared< Resource >( );
        resource->set_path("/hello/{language:[ab-z_]+}");
        resource->set_method_handler( "POST" , print_post);
        service.publish(resource);
    }

    auto settings = make_shared< Settings >( );

    settings->set_port( 1984 );
    service.set_logger( make_shared< CustomLogger >( ) );

    settings->set_default_header( "Connection", "close" );
    service.start( settings );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the resource endpoints?  What client are you using?

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking into it, I'm using curl. 
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "some text" --request POST http://localhost:1984/hello/english
And the log is:
Incoming 'POST' request from '[::1]:61094' for route '/hello/english'.
'[::1]:61094' 'POST' method not allowed '/hello/english'.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out at me. Could you please raise a ticket on the github page with as much information as possible, thanks.

Comment: Ok i will Thanks.

Comment: Sorry failed to update this post.  Short and skinny of the situation is 'language:[a-z_]+' matches 'language:[ab-z_]+' so will never be invoked; fixed in 5.0.